# Error when evaluating ISEMPTY on a cell being edited

Tags: excel, vba, is-empty

I have a repeatable error, but I'm not sure how to account for it.  I'm formulating a filename based on the contents of a few different cells.  If one of the cells is blank I want it to be left out of the mix.  Here is the code:

```
ElseIf SaveChk = 1 Then
    Module1.UserPath = Environ("USERPROFILE")
    Module1.Path = UserPath & "\Desktop\"
    If IsEmpty(Range("Y59")) Then
        Module1.SaveName = Range("AE6").Value & " " & Range("E6").Value
    Else
        Module1.SaveName = Range("AE6").Value & " " & Range("E6").Value & " - " & Range("Y59").Value
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Range("AE59") = Format(Now, "mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM")
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Call HideSheets
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs _
        Filename:=Path & SaveName & ".xlsm", _
        FileFormat:=52
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    MsgBox "Filename = " & SaveName & vbNewLine & "File is saved to your desktop."

Else

    MsgBox "Please Completed Shaded Cells!", vbOK + vbExclamation, "SAVE CANCELLED"

End If

End If

Module1.SaveChk = 0     'Reset SaveChk variable
Module1.BttnChk = 0     'Reset BttnChk variable
Call UnhideSheets

Call Prot

Exit Sub

EH:
Call ErHa
Resume Next

End Sub
```

The code works fine.  However, I get an error when Y59 is in the middle of being edited.  What I mean is, if a user types in a number in Y59 and then clicks on my custom save button instead of completing the cell edit, my save message shown above is displayed but then an error is thrown.  Stepping through the code, the error occurs on the "Exit sub" line of my Save Form sub (which is the one shown above).  I'm trying to account for this usage case, thoughts?

Comment: The issue may be with `Prot` then. Also, you don't need `Call Prot`. Just `Prot` should suffice

Comment: First the call bit, yes its unnecessary but infinitely faster to see what's going on in the code.  Just my coding style.  Second, the two subroutines called hide and unhide sheets (part of a macro enabling system) and the second protects the workbook from unauthorized access.  Maybe the protect command doesn't like an uncompleted cell edit?  ISEMPTY is evaluating based on what the cell value WILL be so maybe its some kind of disconnect.  Aside from what is wrong, I'm trying to figure out how to work-around the issue too.

Comment: So, I disabled my error handling and the Excel error is: Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)': Method 'List' of object '_CommandBarComboBox' failed.

Comment: Well, it looks like there's a conflict with my "Sheet Change" sub which I use to convert pasting to past special values.  Since the text entry isn't "finished" that sub must not be finished and then I activate the save form and sub and it gets cranky.  I'll have to see if I can accomodate that or find another way to convert paste to paste special.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my last comment indicated, the issue involved the "Sheet Change" worksheet sub which I was using to capture paste commands and convert them to paste special value commands.

So, that sub conflicted with the various subs used to validate saving on my worksheet.

I'll have to rework the subs to remove the error or just let it go because the error isn't actually doing anything.